# Using File-Helper to handle extra comma in record CSV parser

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers, fileparsing

I am trying to process a LLarge CSV file - 1Gb where sometimes I may get records where column value has ',' in it.

e.g.

> "A","col1","col2","col3","col4"
>
> "B","Row1","Row1Col2","Row1Col3","Row1Col4"
>
> **"C","Row2","Row2,Col2","Row2,Col3","Row2Col4"**

Initially I used [Split(,)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but for Line C I am getting incorrect data because of extra comma in column value.

I decided to use [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) but it doesn't seems to be extracting values correctly.

When I opened File in Excel it formats it correctly (i.e. shows each value in correct column).

I want to extract all values within double-quotes.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Is the column delimiter a comma ','? So how can Excel split your third line other than at the commas? Did you show us all `"` characters?

Comment: I don't see any extra comma...

Comment: I don't understand how you can be getting the correct values in Excel. I took your three lines, created a file called test.csv, opened it in Excel, and got five columns for rows A and B and seven columns for row C. That's to be expected. How can the software magically determine whether the column is a delimiter or part of the data?

Comment: Gents..Come on this is a genuine problem. Don't down-vote or no reasons

Comment: @JoãoMiguelBrandão if you look carefully you will see Row2Col2 has comma in it

Comment: I see you've edited your question to include quotation marks around the values. Are those actually there in the original source data?

Comment: If you use a proper csv-parser you wouldn't have this problem. Don't reinvent the wheel when there are plenty of libraries already available.

Comment: I have my doubts about the csv-ness of the question's csv :)

Comment: @CraigW. yes they are in the files.

Comment: @J. Steen If you see I am using FileHelpers - now if you type a helpful comment which will resolve my query that will be really helpful !

Comment: @sandeeMPS Obviously it can't handle quoted column values. So use a **proper** csv-parser?

Comment: @J. Steen  proper csv-parser - Any suggestions in your experience.

Comment: @J. Steen  it does handle Quoted columns. Problem is extra "," in column values for a CSV file

Comment: @J.Musser I know that. but where?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting FileHelpers 2.0 to handle CSV files with excess commas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362742/getting-filehelpers-2-0-to-handle-csv-files-with-excess-commas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `FileHelpers` you must use this: `FieldQuotedAttribute`

> FieldQuoted: Indicates that the field must be read and written like a
>   Quoted String. (you can pass the quote char and can set if the quote
>   is optional like the Excel CSV format)

```
[FieldQuoted()] // Quoted with "
public string CustomerName;
```

Comment: which version you see this FieldQuoted attribute. What I have is [FieldQuotedAttribute()]
        public string Address4;

Comment: Since your file is large, be sure to use the asynchronous `FileHelpersAsyncEngine`. See [here](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.FileHelperAsyncEngine.BeginReadFile.html)

Comment: [Updated link](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadWriteRecordByRecord/) for `FileHelpersAsyncEngine`

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

Use [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It parses your lines like Excel does it.

Comment: thanks. but after quick Google I found out that TextFieldParser  is very costly for large files. So can not use it. Thank

Comment: Now, that the question is edited, and all fields are surrounded by qutation-marks, the `TextFieldParser` is the perfect match...

Comment: @sandeeMPS, why not try it first and see if it works in your situation? A "quick Google" may have found you one person's unsubstantiated off-hand comment. Always best to confirm. It would probably take you all of two minutes to figure out whether it would be acceptable in your situation.

Comment: @CraigW. I am wondering IF someone can advise me how to use FileHelper library in this situation